# How do you generally scan/parse commands in interactive REPL programs in C, is there a standard way?

Tags: c, scanf, read-eval-print-loop

I am writing an interactive REPL program in `c`.

Some examples of commands (lines starting with `>`) I would like to handle are:

```
$ ./my_program     // run the program
> add user
id: 123     // this is the output of above command
> update user 123 name "somename"
> remove user 123
> quit
```

So basically the command is a line with multiple strings.

This is how I am trying to handle the commands.

- scan the whole line
- parse the command and get a corresponding `int` value unique to command
- do whatever needs to be done for the command

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int parse_cmd(const char *buffer)
{
    // parse command
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    // init code

    char buffer[100];
    int cmd;
    while (1) {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer);

        cmd = parse_cmd(buffer);
        if (cmd < 0) {
            printf("error: invalid command\n");
            continue;
        }

        switch (cmd) {
            // handle commands
        }
    }

    // deinit code
}
```

There are a lot of cli programs I have seen that take command inputs in similar way.
I wonder if there is a general way of writing cli programs?

I can write code to parse the commands, just wanted to know the standard approach for such situations?

Comment: Don't really understand your question but probably best is to use getline or fgets to get the whole command and parse the string entered, instead of scanf of the input.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I am asking if there is any standard approach to *parse* the commands? Like what would be the contents of the `parse_cmd` function...

Comment: There's not really a standard way to do it. This is not a 100% fair comparison, but your question is kind of like if there is a standard way to construct a compiler, because you are in fact constructing a language, although a very simple one.

Comment: There is no standard approach. 
Apart from using `sscanf` you can use functions like `strchr`, `strtok`, `strsep` (non-standard) or `strpbrk` to find tokens or separators in a string as a base to implement your parser. You could also create a grammar based parser using `lex`/`flex` and `yacc`/`bison`, but this might be too complicated for your simple use case.
I suggest to use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to read the input in order to prevent buffer overflow.. (You have handle the trailing newline and input that is too long for your buffer.)

Comment: FYI: CLI is for command line arguments, what you're asking about is called REPL (read-eval-print-loop).

Answer (score 2):

While there's no real standard way, quite a lot of opensource console tools with an interactive mode use the GNU readline library (https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

It's actually quite easy to use, even simpler than implementing everything 100% correctly by yourself.

Your example rebased on readline:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    // init code

    int cmd;
    char* line;
    while (1) {
        line = readline("> ");
        if (line) {
            cmd = parse_cmd(line);
            switch (cmd) {
                // handle commands
            default:
                printf("error: invalid command\n");
            }
            free(line);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // deinit code
}
```

This isn't any more complex than your example, but you immediately gain:

- command line editing at the interactive prompt, with correct handling of each and every possible terminal
- correct handling of EOF (important if stdin is redirected)
- unlimited input line size

And it's not very hard to add a command history, with arrow-up and down to repeat previous lines, incremental search, optionally persisted to a file, et et.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a standard way to do it. This is not a 100% fair comparison, but your question is kind of like if there is a standard way to construct a compiler, because you are in fact constructing a language, although a very simple one.

But one reasonably common way that works fairly well for simple programs is this approach. Let's assume that we have two commands `add` and `del`. Create a function for both these commands. First we search for one of the strings `"add "` or `"del "`. Notice the spaces. Put a pointer on the next character and call the corresponding function with the rest of the line as argument and allow them to determine things.

Here is some pseudo:

```
parse(bufferptr)
    word = getFirstWord(bufferptr)
    ptr = bufferptr + strlen(word)
    if word == "add"
        return add(ptr)
    else if word == "del"
        return del(ptr)
    return -1

add(bufferptr)  
    word = getFirstWord(bufferptr)
    if userExist(word)
        return -1
    else
        return addUser(word)

del(bufferptr)  
    word = getFirstWord(bufferptr)
    if not userExist(word)
        return -1
    else
        return delUser(word)

buffer = input()
int res = parse(buffer)
```